# HTML img tag with hover issue

Tags: html, css, image, svg

Am having a hard time trying to figure why I cannot get the images here to change color on hover. The images themselves are svg files and should just adopt the color. The code:

HTML:

```
<div class="toolTile col-md-3">
    <a href="#/cards">
        <img src="ppt/assets/toolIcons/requestnewcard.svg" >
        <p>Manage my debit card</p>
    </a>
</div>        
<div class="toolTile col-md-3">
    <a href="#/recurClaim">
        <img src="ppt/assets/toolIcons/recurring.svg" >
        <p>Recurring Claims</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

And associated CSS:

```
.toolTile {
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
}

.toolTile img {
    color: #ab2328;
    height: 100px;
    width: 93px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
}

.toolTile img:hover {
    color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: an svg inside an image tag doesn't belong to your document, it is another and cannot be styled from there. beside  color is only for text and can be inherited by border-color if unset. These make 2 reasons why it doesn't works

Answer (score 0):

Color is related to text elements, you want border.

```css
.toolTile img:hover {
    border: Yellow 1px solid;
}
```

Here is a JSfiddle of it: https://jsfiddle.net/td70mqq5/

If thats not what your looking for, do some research on: `svg {fill: currentColor;}` (https://css-tricks.com/cascading-svg-fill-color/)

Comment: I don't want the border to hover to different color, I want the image to.

Comment: @Mark if svg is inside HTML, you may use fill, not color anyway. you should look for some tutorials ;)

Answer (score 0):

CSS does not apply across document boundaries.  The CSS in your HTML will not be applied to the contents of your external SVG files.

You have to either inline the SVG in your HTML file, or you can move the styles to the SVG file(s) and change the `<img>` elements to `<object>` elements.